# Identifying Unique Visits by Customer

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working in SQL Server and I have a table of CustomerID, VisitDate, Sales, and Quantity.
I'm trying to calculate the average check by visit, so how much does a customer purchase on his/her first repeat purchase, 2nd repeat purchase, etc. Also, how much time passes between each purchase.

Any guidance would be helpful, 
Thanks!

Comment: And what did you try?

Comment: what did you try so far ?

Comment: Why do you call this question "Identifying unique visits"?   What does the subject have to do with the question?

Comment: [Have you tried anything?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` and conditional aggregation.  Here is an exaple:

```
select customerid, avg(sales) as avgsales,
       max(case when segnum = 1 then sales end) as sales_01,
       max(case when segnum = 2 then sales end) as sales_02,
       max(case when segnum = 3 then sales end) as sales_03
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by customerid order by visitdate) as segnum
      from table t
     ) t
group by customerid;
```

By the way, your question really should include sample data, desired results, and the table layout,

Comment: Thanks Gordon! Next time, I'll include sample data.

Comment: You'll notice the question was poorly received.  I understood quite clearly (this is a typical query for data analysis), but others apparently didn't.